# Backbone app: Can't get model data in View

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm building my first, relatively simple Backbone app. Right now, it's fetching JSON of local weather information:

```
Weather = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/api/v1/weather',

    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch({
            success: this.fetchSuccess,
            error: this.fetchError
        });
    },

    parse: function(response) 
    {
        return response;
    },

    fetchSuccess: function (model, response) {
        console.log('FETCH SUCCESS:', response);
    },

    fetchError: function (model, response) {
        throw new Error("FETCH ERROR");
    }
});
```

The above seems to work just fine, as the fetchSuccess console log returns the JSON response as expected.

The problem happens when I attempt to access this data from the view. Here's my code for that:

```
WeatherView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('#widget__weather'),

    initialize: function() 
    {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');

        this.model = new Weather();

        this.model.bind('reset', this.render);

        this.render();
    }, 

    render: function()
    {

        console.log(this.model.toJSON());

        // var template = _.template(weatherTemplate, { weather : this.model });

        // this.$el.html(template);
    }

});
```

The console log for the view is an empty `Object { }`. My attempts to use `this.model.get('timezone')` result in `undefined`.

When I `console.log(this.model`) I get this:

```
  s {cid: "c3", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
    _changing: false
    _events: Object
    _pending: false
    _previousAttributes: Object
    attributes: Object
        currently: Object
        daily: Object
        flags: Object
        headers: Array[13]
        hourly: Object
        minutely: Object
        offset: -4
        timezone: "America/New_York"
    __proto__: Object
    changed: Object
    cid: "c3"
    __proto__: n
```

It seems that my JSON data is in the 'attributes' object of the model, but I don't know why it's there or how to access it.

To be clear, when I do `console.log(this.model.toJSON());` I get an empty `Object { }`.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here and could use any and all help. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible that the structure of the returned JSON data may be causing this? It's a pretty standard response from Forecast.io API.

Let me know if you need any more code / information.

EDIT:

With some help I fixed the issue. Turns out this was the culprit: `this.model.bind('reset', this.render);`. Changing that to `this.model.bind('change', this.render);` fixed the problem.

Comment: (1) `fetch` is an AJAX call so you have no reason to believe that the model will be populated when you try to use it. (2) `console.log` puts a live reference into the console, not a snapshot. By the time you look at it, the AJAX call has returned from the server. (3) `Model#fetch` won't trigger a `'reset'` event, it will trigger a `'change'` event. (4) `Collection#fetch` only triggers a `'reset'` event if you give it the `reset:true` option. (5) I'm sure this question is a duplicate (over and over again) so I'm just commenting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not clear on what you mean in point #1 but thanks for the info about Model fetch not triggering a reset event. Fixing that actually fixed my problem. Also, I searched around a lot for an answer to this before posting, and didn't come across anything that applied to my problem here.

Comment: Do some googling for "JavaScript AJAX", the *A* stands for *asynchronous*. When you make an AJAX call, you send a request to a remove server and get a response at some later time.

Answer (score 0):

yes is correct.

If you write this:

```
console.log(this.model);
```

Uou get the instance of the model, every property that you have parsed are inside `attributes`.

Instead if you use

```
console.log(this.model.toJSON());
```

you transform the instance of the model to a json and you can get directly your property without passing by `attributes`

Then if you wanna print your data inside your template you need to do this:

if you use:

```
var template = _.template(weatherTemplate, { weather : this.model });
```

inside template you need to print your var in this way:

```
weather.attributes.timezone;
```

Instead if you use

```
var template = _.template(weatherTemplate, { weather : this.model.toJSON() });
```

inside template you need to print your var in this way:

```
weather.timezone;
```

Comment: I've tried that already, and all I get is an empty `object { }`.

Comment: Thanks for the response... I tried that but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timezone' of undefined`. It seems that calling `this.model.toJSON()` results in an empty object.